# How to create a cascading SelectList in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I had this working in a different application with the same model values, but I've run into a problem this time around.

What I want to achieve is that when I select one value in one `SelectList`, the values in a different one are changed. This is not currently working.

Say I have the following model:

```
public class DashboardChartsByMonthModel
{
    ...
    public SelectList TimeSliceList { get; set; }
    public TimeSlice TimeSliceVal { get; set; } // Timeslice is an Enum containing "ByMonth" and "ByQuarter"
    public SelectList StartQuarterList { get; set; }
    public string StartQuarter { get; set; }
    public SelectList StartMonthList { get; set; }
    public string StartMonth { get; set; }
    public SelectList StartYearList { get; set; }
    public string StartYear { get; set; }
    ....
    public void SetDefaults()
    {
        ...
        TimeSliceList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "Monthly", Value = TimeSlice.ByMonth.ToString()},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Quarterly", Value = TimeSlice.ByQuarter.ToString()}
        }, "Value", "Text");
}
        StartQuarterList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "Q1", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Q2", Value = "4"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Q3", Value = "7"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Q4", Value = "10"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

        StartMonthList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "January", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "February", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "March", Value = "3"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "April", Value = "4"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "May", Value = "5"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "June", Value = "6"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "July", Value = "7"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "August", Value = "8"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "September", Value = "9"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "October", Value = "10"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "November", Value = "11"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "December", Value = "12"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

        StartYearList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "2016", Value = "2016"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "2017", Value = "2017"}
        }, "Value", "Text");
```

And my view, a Razor(.cshtml) page, has the following:

```
<body>
    ....
    <form method="post">
            <h3>By Month or Quarter</h3>
            <select id="TimeSlice" name="TimeSlice" asp-for="TimeSliceVal" asp-items="@Model.TimeSliceList"></select>
            Start:<select id="StartMonth" name="StartMonth" asp-for="StartMonth" asp-items="@Model.StartMonthList"></select>
            <select id="StartYear" name="StartYear" asp-for="StartYear" asp-items="@Model.StartYearList"></select>
    ....
```

is there a way to have it so that if the value in the first SelectList is Monthly, it displays the values of the MonthList and vice versa so that when the first box is changed, the second box changes as well?

I was able to solve this problem in one of my other applications but it was very cumbersome and relied on both of the SelectLists accessing the same model property.  I imagine there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: @mjwills I would like to solve this client-side.  That is the behavior I do not have that I would like to have.

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan I am not sure how that helps me in any way with this question.

Comment: sorry the question was not clear ( it is a client side problem). Ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty simple to do via javascript. My approach will use JQuery, if you aren't using JQuery there are resources available to help you convert it into native javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TimeSlice").on("change", function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if(val === "Whatever the value of Monthly is here")
        {
            $("#StartMonth").show();
            $("#StartYear").hide();
        }
        else if(val === "Whatever the value of Quarterly is here"){     
            $("#StartYear").show();
            $("#StartMonth").hide();
        }else{
            //If you have any other options in the dropdown, such as a default value or placeholder, this will hide both quarterly and monthly
            $("#StartYear").hide();
            $("#StartMonth").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am including JQuery.  Thanks, Chris.  I will check it out and update.

Comment: Hey Chris, I switched it around in my code but I noticed you use the year instead of quarter.  The year needs to be present in both monthly and quarterly selection.  Also this snippet isn't working.  Both boxes show up and nothing happens on change.  I am including JQuery 3.2.1 in my Bower packages.

Comment: Could be a problem on my end, looking into it.

Comment: In regards to both boxes showing up, you can either add a piece of javascript to the document ready portion of the snippet, that will hide the boxes, or you can set this up in the HTML using `style="display: none;"`, which will force both of the boxes to not show up until the on change function shows one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing complicated to do this. All you do is, first render the first dropdown and listen to the change event of that and read the value and make an ajax call with selected value to the server where it will return the appropriate list of SelectListItems to render the second dropdown.

```
public class DashboardChartsByMonthModel
{
   public List<SelectListItem> TimeSliceList { set;get;}
   public int SelectedTimeSlice { set;get;}

   public List<SelectListItem> TimeOptions{ set;get;}
   public int SelectedTimeOption { set;get;}    
}
```

in your GET action, you load the first dropdown data

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  var vm= new DashboardChartsByMonthModel();
  vm.TimeSliceList = new List<SelectListItem>
  {
        new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "Monthly",
                                             Value = TimeSlice.ByMonth.ToString()},
        new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Quarterly",
                                              Value = TimeSlice.ByQuarter.ToString()}
  };
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your view, use the SELECT tag helper

```
@model DashboardChartsByMonthModel
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home" method="post">    
    <select asp-for="SelectedTimeSlice" asp-items="@Model.TimeSliceList"></select>
    <select id="SelectedTimeOption" name="SelectedTimeOption" 
                                    data-url="@Url.Action("GetTimes")"></select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The javascript to handle change event is pretty simple with jQuery

```
$(function () {

    $("#SelectedTimeSlice").change(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        var url = $("#SelectedTimeOption").data("url") + '?value=' + v;
        $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
                $("#SelectedTimeOption").empty();
                $.each(data,
                    function(i, item) {
                        $("#SelectedTimeOption")
                     .append($("<option>").text(item.text).val(item.value));
                    });
            });
    });

});
```

This expects you have an action method which accepts the selected option value  of first dropdown and return the options needed for second.

```
public IActionResult GetTimes(string value)
{
    if (value == TimeSlice.ByMonth.ToString())
    {
        var l = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "January", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "February", Value = "2"}
        };
        return Json(l);
    }
    var t2 = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = "Q1", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Q2", Value = "2"}
    };
    return Json(t2);
}
```

The important to thing to notice is, In asp.net core the returned JSON is camel case. So for each select option, it is `text` and `value` instead of `Text` and `Value`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply!  I will check it out tomorrow.