# How to create cascading drop-down list

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**I have two dropdown list for filtering purpose.How can I change this dropdown list to catchcadaing dropdownlist**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        REFINED_DBEntities db = new REFINED_DBEntities();
        ViewBag.Subdivision =
            new SelectList(db.Retention_Model_Predictions_DS_Manual.Select(m => m.Subdivision).Distinct().OrderBy(c=>c.ToUpper()),

            "Subdivision");

        ViewBag.UnderwriterName =
            new SelectList(db.Retention_Model_Predictions_DS_Manual.Select(m => m.Underwriter_Name).Distinct(),

                "Underwriter_Name");
        return View();
    }
```

**HTML view**

```
<div class="form-group ">
    @Html.DropDownList("Subdivision", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Subdivision, "Select Region", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "subDivision" })

</div>

<div class="form-group ">
    @Html.DropDownList("Underwriter_Name", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UnderwriterName, "Select Underwriter", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "uwriter" })
</div>
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. You probably want to use an AJAX call once the first dropdown is selected to populate the second one. Try googling: "cascading dropdown"

Comment: Where did you hear the term **catchcadaing** ?

Comment: Here is a sample to start with . This is for asp.net core, but the concept is same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942151/how-to-create-a-cascading-selectlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc/46942859#46942859

Comment: @Shyju: it's cascading, but who cares about few letters ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of cascading drop-down is, you select a value in the first drop-down, and it triggers some action to load the options for a second drop-down. A classic example is Country drop-down down and State drop-down. Every time user selects a country the country drop-down should be updated with the states under that country.

**I am going to give you a very generic example of the Country-State use case. You can use the same concepts to build your specific use case**

To start with ,  create a view model for your view. Create a property of type `List<SelectListItem>` for passing the list of options needed for building the SELECT element and another property to store the selected option value. We will do this for both the SELECT elements.

```
public class CreateUserVm
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Countries { set;get;}
   public int SelectedCountryId { set;get;}

   public List<SelectListItem> States { set;get;}
   public int SelectedStateId { set;get;}  

   public CreateUserVm()
   {
     this.Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
     this.States = new List<SelectListItem>();
   }  
}
```

Now in your GET action method, create an object of this view model, initialize the options for the first dropdown , in this case the `Countries` property and send that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
    var vm=new CreateUserVm();
    vm.Countries = GetCountries();
    return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetCountries()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Value = "1", Text = "USA"},
        new SelectListItem() {Value = "2", Text = "India"},
    };
    return list;
}
```

Now in your View, which is strongly typed to our view model. we will use the `DropDownListFor` helper method to render the drop-downs

```
@model CreateUserVm
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.SelectedCountryId,Model.Countries,"Select one")
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedStateId, Model.States, "Select one",
                                              new { data_url = Url.Action("GetStates") })
   <input type="Submit" />
}
```

This will render 2 dropdowns, one with `Country` options and the second one will be empty (because we did not load anything to the `States` property). Now we will have some javascript(we are using jquery here for easy DOM manipulation)  which will listen to the `change` event of the first drop-down(Country) ,read the selected value and make an ajax call to the `GetStates` method and passing the selected country option value.

You can see that , i set a html5 data attribute for the second dropdown where i am storing the url to the `GetStates` method. So in my javascript, i can simply read this data attribute value and make a call to that url to get the data.

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectedCountryId").change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        var url = $("#SelectedStateId").data("url") + '?countryId=' + v;
        var $states = $("#SelectedStateId");
        $.getJSON(url, function (states) {
                $states.empty();
                $.each(states, function (i, item) {
                    $states.append($("<option>").text(item.Text).val(item.Value));
                });
            });    
    });
});
```

Now, let's add a `GetStates` action method which accepts the `countryId` and return the states for that country in a list of `SelectListItem` as JSON array.

```
public ActionResult GetStates(int countryId)
{
    var states = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (countryId == 1)
    {
        states.Add(new SelectListItem() {Value = "101", Text = "Michigan"});
        states.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "102", Text = "New York" });
    }
    else if (countryId == 2)
    {
        states.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "103", Text = "Kerala" });
        states.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "104", Text = "Goa" });

    }
    return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here i have hard coded the Countries and States. But if you have a database which has this data, replace the hard coded values with data from your tables.

When you are editing a record, All you have to do is, load the `States` property in the GET action based on the CountryId which is saved.

Comment: Spelling error in *public AcitonResult Create()* should be *public ActionResult Create().*

Also an error "not all code paths return value" in 
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var vm = new CreateUserVm();
            vm.Countries = GetCountries();
        }

Comment: How would you implement the above solution using an entity framework?

Comment: Fixed the typo and the missing return statement. It does not matter what data access technology you are using. Once you have the above approach (Hard coded values) working, all you have to do is, replace the hard coded items with dynamic data coming from a table. There are tons of examples to do so in Stackoverflow.  Here is one to start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc/34624217#34624217 (See the Getting data from your database table using entity framework part of the answer)

Comment: Thanks.  How could I implement the above using JQuery instead of JavaScript?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. the above code is using jQuery for easy DOM manupulations