# ASP.NET MVC cascading dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have three tables in my database as follows:

```
University 
 id   Name
 1     A
 2     B

Faculty 
id   id_uni   name
1      1       AA
2      1       AA

cafedry
id    id_uni    id_faculty   name

1       1            1        cc
```

I would like to create a cascading dropdown which will allow me to first select a University then a Faculty followed by a Cafedry. Below code is what i have tried so far.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.fak_kod = new SelectList(db.Fakulteler, "id", "adi");
        ViewBag.unikod = new SelectList(db.Universitetler, "id", "adi");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: kafedras/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,unikod,fak_kod,adi")] kafedra kafedra)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.kafedra.Add(kafedra);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.fak_kod = new SelectList(db.Fakulteler , "id", "adi", kafedra.fak_kod);
        ViewBag.unikod = new SelectList(db.Universitetler, "id", "adi", kafedra.unikod);
        return View(kafedra);
    }
```

and this cshtml

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>kafedra</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.unikod, "unikod", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("unikod", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.unikod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fak_kod, "fak_kod", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("fak_kod", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fak_kod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can update this code to create a cascading dropdown with the three tables?

Comment: So you want to implement cascading dropdown ?

Comment: yes  actually give me manually select in dropwdown bu i want cascading  for example select university AA then in faculty dropdwon show which  faculty have a in university

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954959/how-to-create-cascading-drop-down-list

Comment: was see but dont was help me

Comment: Why is there a need for [id_uni] in the [cafedry] table? The link between [cafedry] table and [University] table exists via the [Faculty] table

Answer (score 3):

To start with, create a view model which has properties to render the options and store the selected item value.

```
public class CreateVm
{
   [Required]
   public int SelectedUniversity { set;get;}

   [Required]
   public int SelectedFaculty { set;get;}  

   public List<SelectListItem> Universities { set;get;}    
   public List<SelectListItem> Faculties { set;get;}

   public CreateVm()
   {
       this.Faculties = new List<SelectListItem>();
       this.Universities = new List<SelectListItem>();
   }  
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, load the `Universities` property and send the object to the view

```
public AcitonResult Create()
{ 
   var vm=new CreateVm();
   vm.Universities= GetUniversities();
   return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetUniversities()
{
    return db.Universitetler
             .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id,
                                             Text = x.Name)
             .ToList();
}
```

Now in your View, which is strongly typed to our `CreateVm` view model. we will use the `DropDownListFor` helper method to render the drop-downs

```
@model CreateVm
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.SelectedUniversity,Model.Universities,"Select one")
   @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedFaculty , Model.Faculties, "Select one",
                                       new { data_url = Url.Action("GetFaculties") })
   <input type="Submit" />
}
```

This will render 2 dropdowns, one with University options and the second one will be empty (because we did not load anything to the `Faculties` property). Now we will have some javascript(we are using jquery here for easy DOM manipulation) which will listen to the change event of the first drop-down(Universities) ,read the selected value and make an ajax call to the `GetFaculties` method and passing the selected university option value.

You can see that , i set a html5 data attribute for the second dropdown where i am storing the relative url to the `GetFaculties` method. So in my javascript, i can simply read this data attribute value and make a call to that url to get the data.

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectedUniversity").change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        var url = $("#SelectedFaculty").data("url") + '?u=' + v;
        var $fac= $("#SelectedFaculty");
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $fac.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $fac.append($("<option>").text(item.Text).val(item.Value));
                });
            });    
    });
});
```

Now, let's add a `GetFaculties` action method which accepts the university id and return the faculties for that university in a list of `SelectListItem` as JSON array.

```
public ActionResult GetFaculties(int u)
{
    var facultyList = db.Fakulteler
                        .Where(a=>a.id_uni==u)
                        .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value=x.Id,
                                                       Text=x.Name).ToList();
    return Json(facultyList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You may use the same view model in the HttpPost action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateVm vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //read from vm and save
        var k=new kafedra { 
                           UniveristyId=vm.SelectedUniversity, 
                           FacultyId=vm.SelectedFaculty, 
                        };
        db.kafedra.Add(k);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    vm.Universities= GetUniversities();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.but i see in asp net web forms very easy for giving this result

Comment: Nice. The only thing I would recommend is using JQuery instead of Javascript to avoid a postback.