# auto populate the value of 2 dropdowns based on the textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 1 table in my database with employee name, department name and branch name. now i want, when employee enter his name in name field then the corresponding department and branch name values will auto populate in the respective drop-down.
how to do it in Dot Net MVC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC cascading dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252378/asp-net-mvc-cascading-dropdown)

Comment: Please search your question before you ask yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax and a corresponding function in the controller.

[for further reading & sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084568/populate-dropdownlist-using-ajax-mvc-4)