# How to set a default value on Select and saving that value to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm fairly new to C# and javascript, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong :P

I'm trying to make a dropdown to depend on another dropdown in C# where I've faced the issue of the value taken from the first dropdown being null when nothing has been selected from the dropdown.

I have two classes in the controller, one for the first dropdown that consists of the "categories" and one that consists of the "under-categories/sub categories":

```
public ActionResult RenderCategories(int id)
    {
        DataTable UserTbl = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Category_Title,CID FROM CategoryTbl", sqlConn);
            sqlDa.Fill(UserTbl);
        }
        return View(UserTbl);

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult RenderUnderCategories(int? value) // This value is null when no value has been choosen from dropdown 1
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
        DataTable UserTbl = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            value = 1;
            if (value != null) {
                
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT uCID,under_category_Title FROM UndercategoryTbl where CID =" + value + "", sqlConn);
                sqlDa.Fill(UserTbl);    
            } 
        }
        return Json(new { data = UserTbl }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I then have two different views with the respective dropdown:

Dropdown 1:

```
<select id="Categories-Dropdown">
    <option>- Select Category -</option>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <option value="@Model.Rows[i]["CID"]" name="CategoryID">@Model.Rows[i]["Category_Title"]</option>
    }
</select>
```

I also have some script for dropdown 1 that takes the value (which is an id) to the controller:

```
<script>
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('Categories-Dropdown');
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
        showValue(this.value);
        
    })
    
    function showValue(val)
{
    console.log(val);
        $.getJSON('/ScannableNotes/RenderUnderCategories/?value=' + val)
}
</script>
```

The value taken from the onchange event is crucial because that determines which values will be shown in dropdown 2, making the dropdowns dependant on each other.

In order to make the dropdowns appear in the same view, I'm using the render action method in a third view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("RenderCategories","ScannableNotes");}
@{Html.RenderAction("RenderUnderCategories", "ScannableNotes");} //error appears here
```

However, when executing the code the following error appears at the render action of dropdown 2:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'

I assume this is because the value taken from dropdown 1 to the controller of dropdown 2 (RenderUnderCategories) is null when no value has been choosen. And the value won't be true until I choose something in dropdown 1 which will trigger the onchange event.

So my question is, how can I set a default value on the Select for dropdown 1 and then take that value to the controller?

Comment: Here's an answer for cascading drop down https://stackoverflow.com/a/47252608/2030565

Comment: Please be aware your query code could be vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider using parameterized queries https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet.html