# How to automatic update second DropDown on.change first, included LiveSearch?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdown included live search.

First is Barcode of Article, Second is Name of Article, also automated load Price, and tax of article, but work in this moment.

My question is  when  i choice Barcode of any article How to update name of article in secund Dropdown (You can see second image, second dropdown is just Default text, not updating article name by Barcode of article choice), or if i choice Article Name to update first dropdown Barcode dropdown by selected Article Name, using Javascript?

example on pictures:

[Image First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bshu.png)

[Image Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cERMQ.png)

**LOAD ARTICLE NAME BY BARCODE CHOICE**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/fakturi/getArticles?CompanyID=" + cID, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                $('<option>',
                   {
                       value: data.artID,
                       text: data.artCode
                   }).html;
            });
        })
        $(function () {
            $("[name='bar']").on("change", function () {
                $("#artikal").val($(this).val());
            });
        });
    });
```

**LOAD BARCODE BY CHOICE ARTICLE NAME**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/fakturi/getArticles?CompanyID=" + cID, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
            $('<option>',
               {
                   value: data.artID,
                   text: data.artIme
               }).html;
        });
    })
    $(function () {
        $("[name='artikal']").on("change", function () {
            $("#bar").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: My Question is when i choice Barcode of any article How to update name of article in secund Dropdown (You can see second image, second dropdown is just Default text, not updating article name by Barcode of article choicing), or if i choice Article Name to update first dropdown Barcode

Comment: you need to make an ajax call to get the data for the second dropdown on the change event of first dropdown. Refer [How to create cascading drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957086/40521) for cascading dropdowns.

Comment: I have ajax, and also if i remove livesearch work property without live search. When i add Livesearch to dropdown problem started.

Comment: Anyone Solution or Idea ?

Comment: I still do not understand what your specific problem is ? What is "live search". There is no native method called "live search" on a dropdown control. User can only select an item from a SELECT element.

Comment: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search Here is example of Livesearch dropdown.

Comment: Now is Clear my question ?