# Cascading dropdowns using MVC Razor Entity Framework and stored procedures

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, cascadingdropdown

I am new to MVC and Razor and have looked at so many examples and tutorials of this but have not been able to get it working. It seems so simple but I think the fact that I am trying to use stored procedures complicates everything.

I am trying to create a few simple cascading dropdowns in MVC using stored procedures and entity framework.

My entity consists of the following stored procedures:

[image]

```
exec prcGetMakes
exec prcGetModels 'BMW'
exec prcGetVariants '1 SERIES 5-DOOR'
```

I created a view model class called VehicleViewModel:

```
public class VehicleViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string BrandID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string ModelID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Variant")]
    public string VariantName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Model { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Variant { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the default controller class called `HomeController.cs`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    VehicleInfoEntities db = new VehicleInfoEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var app = new VehicleViewModel
        {
            Manufacturer = GetMakes()
        };

        return View(app);
    }


    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMakes()
    {
        var list = new VehicleViewModel();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> manufacturer = from s in db.prcGetMakes(null)
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Selected = s.ToString() == "Active",
                                                Text = s.BrandName,
                                                Value = s.BrandID
                                            };
        return manufacturer;

    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetModels(string brandName)
    {
        var list = new VehicleViewModel();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> models = from s in db.prcGetModels(brandName)
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Selected = s.ToString() == "Active",
                                                Text = s.ModelName,
                                                Value = s.ModelID
                                            };
        return models;

    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetVariants(string modelName)
    {
        var list = new VehicleViewModel();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> variants = from s in db.prcGetVariants(modelName)
                                             select new SelectListItem
                                             {
                                                 Selected = s.ToString() == "Active",
                                                 Text = s.VariantName,
                                                 Value = s.VariantName
                                             };
        return variants;

    }
}
```

This is my view

```
@model WebApplication12.Models.VehicleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Sample", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
    @Html.Label("Manufacturer:", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Manufacturer", ViewData["Manufacturer"] as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div><br />

}
```

The desired outcome is

[image]

I would just like to know now how to use JQuery to make the cascading DropDowns work and filter on selection of each DropDown.

Comment: You can certainly used stored procedures, although things like lookup tables are pretty simple with plain entity framework. You would probably want to develop a Vehicle entity model that would most likely have fields like VehicleId, ManufacturerId, ModelId, VariantId, etc. Then you might create a VehicleViewModel where you would have things you need for the View like the drop down list collections, etc. So then your controller populates the view model and displays the view. Lots of good tutorials out there.

Comment: Take a look at [How to create cascading drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957086/40521)

Comment: Thanks,the solution in the link doesn't work, there are spelling errors and the one and the *public ActionResult Create()* gives an error "not all code paths return a value", also how would I use entity framework with this?

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks for your answer and advice. 

I know at a high level what you are saying and I have seen many tutorials but I was hoping for specific code as an example based on my actual entity and model. As I said, I'm new to MVC. 

You are correct, there are many tutorials but none that use my model and entity and as a beginner it was quite hard to adapt existing tutorials.

Comment: You may be biting off too much at once. Maybe start with a simple Vehicle Model that is just a VehicleId and VehicleDescription. Get the Model, View and Controller CRUD working. Then add a single drop down list. Then do the cascading part. Etc.

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks, I decided to do just that and I have managed to get the Model, View and Controller CRUD working.  Now I just need to figure out how to use some JQuery in my View to make the cascading dropdowns work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to thick client apps, web cascading drop down lists are convoluted and complex, but that's web programming! Keep in mind that javascript doesn't care about your MVC stuff at all. You just need a web method (something that responds to web URL) that takes a parameter and returns the correct list in the correct format. Whatever method it uses internally (EF stored procedure, hard coded list, PHP reading a text file) doesn't make any difference

To do what you want, you need to add an "event handler" to your drop down which calls some javascript which calls your method to look up the correct list, then populates the target drop down with that list.

I'll put some sample code here but

- there is a degree of 'wiring up' required (using the correct names of things)
- I'm going to make some assumptions
- I learnt this from the web and some syntax may be incorrect

So first add an onchange event handler to your drop down so that when somehing is changed it fires some javascript code

```
@Html.DropDownList("Manufacturer", 
                   ViewData["Manufacturer"] as SelectList, 
                   htmlAttributes: 
                         new { @class = "form-control" , 
                               @onchange = "refreshModelFromManufacturer()"
                             }
                   )
```

When the drop down value is changed it will call javascript function `refreshModelFromManufacturer()`

Here is the javascript function. Hopefully you know how to add this. It requires you to also have a drop down with name "Model" (which you don't have in your view yet so add it):

```
function refreshModelFromManufacturer()() {
    // get references to the source and target drop downs html controls
    // These are jquery searches to find the drop down controls

    // find a control with id=Manufacturer
    src = $("#Manufacturer");

    // find a control with id=Model (you need to add this to your view)
    tgt = $("#Model");

    // clear drop down
    tgt.empty();

    // Get new model dataset via ajax 
    // based on manufacturer
    // The url parameter points at your web method
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Home/GetModels',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { brandName: src.val() },
        // success is called when dataset returns
        success: function (p) {
                // Populate with each returned member
                $.each(p, function (i, pr) {
                    tgt.append(
                        '<option value="' + pr.Value + '">' +
                        pr.Text + '</option>'
                        );
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the most likely place that things will go wrong. Javascript is unforgiving, case sensitive, and has waaaaay too many brackets that are easily messed up. Make sure you are using source control so you can roll back because it can be impossible to work out a misplaced bracket sometimes because the code fails somewhere deep inside the jquery library, giving you no clue

The last thing is that your web method needs to be of type Json so that the ajax call works

```
public JsonResult GetModels(string brandName)
{
    var list = db.prcGetModels(brandName)

    return Json(new SelectList(list, "your id column","your label column"));
}
```

The only other difference in my code is that actually define a drop down just like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Customer_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-
control", @onchange = "refreshProjectFromClient()" })
```

I think that if your ViewBag name is the same as your drop down, then you don't need to explicitly define the viewbag (my second parameter is null)

For debugging (because this won't work first time), make sure you know how to use the F12 debugger to debug javascript as well as observe internal web calls (the network tab). For example when you run this, you should see calls to the `Home/GetModels` method in the network tab

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed example and explanation.  I was able to use this to get my solution working :)

Comment: Oh great to hear!