# MVC Dependent Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MCategoryId, "Üst Kategori Adı", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("MCategoryId", null,"Kategori Seçiniz", htmlAttributes: new { id = "category1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, "Sub Kategori Adı", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hi when i click on the category, i want to open the subcategory. Just like this. http://jsfiddle.net/v917ycp6/5/

Comment: This is also known as having Cascading Dropdowns. See if this will help you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/ - or this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/883701/An-ASP-NET-MVC-Cascading-Dropdown-List

Comment: Listen to the change event on first dropdown, get the data for second dropdown using an ajax call and fill it. Refer this post [How to create cascading drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954959/how-to-create-cascading-drop-down-list)