# asp.net core - cascading dropdown from single table

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to approach a cascading dropdownlist in asp.net core mvc using one single table. I have following fields:

```
 public int DeptId { get; set; }
     public string Division { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
     public string Designation { get; set; }
```

I would like to know what do I have to develop in order to create a cascading dropdown where in the first dropdown displays Division data, in the second one displays DepartmentName data and in third one display designation associated to the selected **Division**.

I have 1st drop down which shows all division here is my code

Controller

```
       public ActionResult Edit()
        {
  ViewBag.StateList = db.Depts;

            return View();


        }
```

Html

```
@Html.DropDownList("dept", new SelectList(ViewBag.StateList, "DeptId", "Division"), "---Select Department---", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

i need to do this cascading dropdown from **single** table.  "Department"

Comment: Where are you stuck ? listen to the change event on the SELECT element, read the selected option value (deptId) and send to an action method which can query the table with a `WHERE DeptId=yourDeptId` and return a JSON array to your client side code(ajax call) where you will populate the second dropdown. It does not matter whether data is coming from one table or 2 tables. Since all the data is in the same table,  you probably want to use DISTINCT to get the unique records

Comment: kindly can you write a small code for help if its possible for you?

Comment: Did you try it yourself ? There are tons of examples in SO for cascading dropdown. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957086/40521) to get started. Once you have it working with the hard coded items, it is a matter of switching the hard coded items with data from your table.