# How can I get the selected item in dropdownlistbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like u to help me to find the selected it in dropdownlistbox selected item

when I build the site
there are two methods of create

1. Get - before the page post back
2. Post - after I pressed the submit button

I have two listboxes

Yatzran which I have all the options available

and degem

after I choose Yatzran

I can connect to db.carlist2

to get all degem of a particular yatzran

and then I can filter degem accordingly the yatzran selectedlist item

BUT I want to get it before Before I press the submit button

I try the request.form 
and also the hidden field 
and it didn't work.

this is the code I have of yatzran

```
var Yatzran = db.CarList2.Select(u => u.Yatzran);
ViewBag.Yatzran = new SelectList(Yatzran.Distinct());
```

this is working and I get all Yatzran list

I try to get the degem accordingly to yatzran selecteditem

```
var DegemID = ViewBag.Degem.Single(s => s.Yatzran == 
ViewBag.Yatzran.selectedvalue).ID;
```

This line do not work

Please help me :)

Comment: What is the type of Yatzran.selectedvalue? It looks like you may be comparing two different types in the linq expression `s.Yatzran == ViewBag.Yatzran.selectedvalue`.

Comment: Is this in the view?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement cascading dropdown. Refer this [How to create cascading drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954959/how-to-create-cascading-drop-down-list)

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for a working example of cascading dropdownlists

Comment: I try to do something like this

Comment: var Yatzran = db.CarList2.Select(u => u.Yatzran);

            ViewBag.Yatzran = new SelectList(Yatzran.Distinct());



       


            string val = Convert.ToString(Request.Params["hdnProjectName"]);
          



            var Degem = db.CarList2.Select(u => u.Degem);

            ViewBag.Degem = new SelectList(Degem.Distinct());


            string text = ViewBag.Degem.Where(val).FirstOrDefault().Text;


            ViewBag.Degem = new SelectList(text);