# Populate state dropdown based on country selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this 2 drop downs country and state. I need to populate or refresh the state dropdown values based on the country selected. How do I do this without the database?

helper class :

```
public class List
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatesList()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="--Select a state--", Value=""},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Alabama", Value="AL"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Alaska", Value="AK"},
            new SelectListItem() { Text="Arizona", Value="AZ"}

        };

        IList<SelectListItem> states1 = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="--Select a state--", Value=""},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Alberta", Value="AB"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="British Columbia", Value="BC"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Manitoba", Value="MB"}

        };
        return states;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> country = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "--Select a Country--", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem() {Text= "Canada", Value = "Can"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Unites States of America", Value = "USA"}
        };
        return country;
    }
}
```

View :

```html
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, Myproject.Helpers.List.GetCountryList(), new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "--Select a country--" })
 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, Myproject.Helpers.List.GetCountryList(), new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "--Select a country--" })
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to listen to the `change` event of first dropdown and then populate the second dropdown options. Refer this [How to create cascading drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954959/how-to-create-cascading-drop-down-list)

Comment: The Canadian ones are provinces...so it should be "Select a province" for those options